# Stored procedure returning DateTime format

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure as following,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Access_GetDate]
(
    @Name varchar(255)
)
AS
    SELECT TOP(1) Employee.StartDate 
    FROM Employee 
    WHERE Employee.Name = @Name;
```

its working properly but returning date in this format

```
2012-10-24 00:00:00.000
```

However I want it in this format,

```
2012 10 24
```

only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Access_GetDate]
(
    @Name varchar(255)
)
AS

SELECT TOP(1) replace(convert(char(10), Employee.StartDate, 120), '-', ' ') StartDate
FROM Employee 
WHERE Employee.Name = @Name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5530)